# Is there any way to get botUserData for other user in conversation on MS bot framework

Tags: c#, botframework

Is there any way to get botUserData for other user in conversation.

Now when I have Bot.Connector.Message a can get/change global data for current user, and data for conversation for all users. But I want to get access to gobal data for others user in conversation. I can get participants list for this dialog by IList Participants, but how to get user data for these participant?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this yet, but I think that using the ConnectorClient will make the trick. It has a method "GetPerUserConversationData" under the Bots collection where you can specify the botId, conversationId and userId.

Hope this helps,
Ez.

Comment: I think it's data per user in this conversation, but i whant to get access to general user container...

Answer (score 0):

Ejadib is right; you can use the GetUserData API where you can specify the user by passing in the user you intend to get the profile for.

In this way for example you can update the per-bot profile of the user listed in the "UserAddedToConversation" system message.

More info about the API's is available in the reference:

http://docs.botframework.com/sdkreference/restapi/#navtitle